# Convert NSString in 12 hour time format

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

In my project I have an NSString that contains data like this

```
NSString *s=@"20";
```

I want to convert this as "08:00 ". How can I do this?

I tried this one:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSString* dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:@"20"];
```

but I am getting this dateString as null value.

Comment: `stringFromDate` expects you to pass an NSDate, but you are passing it an NSString.

Comment: then how can convert string as above

Comment: Try to use below answer.These answer working perfect.

Comment: They "work". But that doesn't mean they are the right way to go about it.

Comment: @Abizem You know this answer according to user.Because user wanna like this.And these type of functionality is provided by apple so what's the wrong.

Comment: @user2197875 if you got your answer then accept answer....

Answer (score 3):

You input as `NSString`, need output as `NSString`.

So intermediate work of `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter` are not required.

You can attain this by :

```
NSString *s=@"20";
NSString *time=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:00",[s integerValue]%12];
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use this one .I hope it will work fine...

```
NSString *s=@"20";    
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:s];

[df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSString *newTime = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Time : %@",newTime);
```